# how to check multiple values of a result from ajax request in jquery's if statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rows, dynamically-generated

hi i have an ajax request where i am sending some request to an php file through ajax and the request is generating a result so far everything is working good but now i want to keep some validations for my results. i am doing this on dynamically added table rows so if the validations is are not met it wont allow to add a new row but still after validating it is adding rows can anybody help in fixing my issue thanks
here is my code

```
  $("#savetodb").removeAttr("disabled");
  var vendor      = $("#sub_vendor_id"+rowcount+">option:selected").val();
  var product     = $("#prodid_"+rowcount).val();
  var productname = $("#prod_"+rowcount).val();
  var vouchdt     = $("#dateinfo").val();
  var qty         = $("#quantity_"+rowcount).val();
  var amt         = $("#amount_"+rowcount).val();
  $.get("../model/check_product_with_invoice_number.php", { invno : invoice, product : product, vendor : vendor, date : vouchdt, quantity : qty, amount : amt }, function (result) { 
        if(result == "") {
          alert(productname+" Does not exist for invoice number "+id);
          $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       }
       if(result == 2) {
          alert("Quantity "+ qty +" for "+productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
          $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       }           
       if(result == 3) {
          alert("Amount "+amt +" For "+productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
          $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       }
if(result !=='' && result !==3 && result !==2){
$("#savetodb").removeAttr("disabled");
append_row('enable remove','',prods,unitid,unitcode);
}
});
```

here is my php

```
$code     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["invno"]); 
$vendor   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["vendor"]); 
$product  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["product"]); 
$vouchdt  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["date"]);
$amt      = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["amount"]);
$qty      = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["quantity"]);


$chkquantity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gc_procurement_daily_detail` WHERE quantity_procured='".$qty."'
                            AND product_id='".$product."' AND sub_vendor_id='".$vendor."'")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($chkquantity)> 0){

$chkamt  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gc_procurement_daily_detail` WHERE procured_detail_amount='".$amt."'
                        AND product_id='".$product."' AND sub_vendor_id='".$vendor."' AND quantity_procured='".$qty."'")or die(mysql_error());                            

if(mysql_num_rows($chkamt)>0){

$chkinvoice = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.* FROM `gc_procurement_daily_detail` a, `gc_procurement_daily_summary` b 
                           WHERE  a.sub_vendor_id='".$vendor."' AND a.product_id='".$product."' AND
                           a.quantity_procured='".$qty."' AND a.procured_detail_amount='".$amt."' AND
                           b.`date_of_invoice`='".$vouchdt."' AND b.invoice_number='".$code."' AND
                           a.`procurement_daily_summary_id`= b.procurement_daily_summary_id")or die(mysql_query());

$minv     = mysql_fetch_object($chkinvoice);
$fininv   = $minv->invoice_number;

if($code == $fininv){
   echo 1;  
   exit;
}else{
   echo '';
   exit;
}

}else{
   echo 3;      
   exit;
}
}else{
    echo 2;
    exit;   
}
```

Comment: php if else is right, but you should do some code formatting :D

Comment: yup thanks fr the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just warp the ajax conditions inside double quote

```
if(result !=='' && result !=="3" && result !=="2")
```

And this for all of them.

as this answer has been chosen as best answer 
i would suggest to combine other ideas also that you should chain your conditions in

```
if(){
}else if(){
}
```

an so on or use

```
Switch (result){
case 1:
//Do logic of this case here
break;

case 2:
//Do logic of this case here
break;

}
```

so you will have benefit of exiting execution whenever your condition achieved

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

for the js part, you could use a switch for this:

```
switch(result){
    case 2 : //error break;
    case 3 : //error break;
    case 4 : //error break;
    default: //save stuff break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement instead, like so:

```
switch(result){
    case '':
        alert(productname+" Does not exist for invoice number "+id);
        $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    break;
    case '2':
        alert("Quantity "+ qty +" for "+productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
        $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    break;
    case '3':
        alert("Amount "+amt +" For "+productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
        $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    break;
    default:
        $("#savetodb").removeAttr("disabled");
        append_row('enable remove','',prods,unitid,unitcode);
    break;
}
```

***Your result is probably coming back as a string not an integer so you will probably need to wrap the numbers with quotes.***